# Remove loaded element after fancybox closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fancybox-3

How can I delete the loaded data through a `ajax` call so that when I press on another image the relative images are loaded?

This is my code for loading `fancybox`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
        loop: false,
        closeExisting: true,
        buttons: [
            // "zoom",
            //"share",
            "slideShow",
            // "fullScreen",
            //"download",
            // "thumbs",
            "close"
        ],
        onInit: function (instance) {
            let id_album = $("[data-fancybox]").attr('id');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: './function/retrive-photo.php',
                data: {
                    id_album: id_album
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                        instance.addContent({
                            'type': 'image',
                            'src': item.src
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        },
        afterClose: function () {
            $('.fancybox-content').remove();
            console.log("DONE B!");
        }
    });
});
```

I try to delete the content of the `fancybox` loaded via `ajax` using the command `$('.fancybox-content').remove()`but it doesn't work

Comment: Perhaps ` $(this).remove();` ?

Comment: @LeeTaylor Nope, it doesn't work. When I click on another image, the images that are loaded are those that were previously uploaded

Comment: Without a working demo to play with it's hard to see the issue.

Comment: You can see the problem at this link: http://foobanizer.altervista.org/photography.php

Comment: You have an error in your code `instance.hideLoading( slide )`

Comment: @LeeTaylor Oh sorry, It's a my test. I just remove the line

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem. I can click on images and they load up.

Comment: @LeeTaylor If you click on the first image it will load the correct images. Afterwards, if you press on the second image (bottom right) you will reload the images from before and not those related to the album

Comment: Please see my answer. Add any comments to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your

```
onInit: function (instance) 
{
    let id_album = $("[data-fancybox]").attr('id');
```

to:

```
onInit: function (instance) 
{
    let id_album = $("[data-fancybox]").eq(instance.id-1).attr("id");
```

Since `$("[data-fancybox]")` is an array, you are getting its `id` which will always give you the first one.

**EDIT**

Change :

```
$("[data-fancybox]").fancybox(
{
   XXX
});
```

to:

```
$("[data-fancybox]").each(function() 
{
    var that = this;
    $(this).fancybox(
    {
        XXX
    });
});
```

Then change your onInit code to:

```
let id_album = $(that).attr('id');
```

Comment: And if I have a number of images other than 2? Which I don't know because it can increase or decrease based on the number of albums that are loaded?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that as long as you use the same mechanism that it will work. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: If I use the same solution you suggested, it doesn't work. If I start to look at the gallery from the fifth image I upload the photos of the first one because it takes the id of the first image.

Comment: Can you upload to your site?

Comment: I just updated! Also, I noticed that as a second image it always shows me the cover of the album that is there before. If, for example, I press on the third image (bottom right), as a second image the gallery shows me the image at the top left.

Comment: OK. I've made an edit to my answer. It's hard to test without being able to edit the code. So hopefully that's closer. I could be wrong, but I think you can just miss out the initial image from the php call...